# Setting up VNC client environment for Cloud 9 development

Tags: amazon-ec2, vnc, aws-cloud9

I am trying to use the Cloud9 IDE to display a GUI so that it will be able to display a project I have written in SDL. Trouble is, Cloud9 does not have any video output.

There are tutorials online to connect to VNC from Cloud 9 environment, however, they are very old and some of those steps do not apply to the current AWS C9 setup.

The VNC I have tried to setup is Cloud9 to VNC via **x11vnc**: https://github.com/acabey/cloud9-vnc.

I get the following output when I run the shell script via custom shell runner:

```
Your GUI is running at https://"myPublicIP"/vnc.html.

VNC client running at https://"myPublicIP"/vnc.html.
Starting c9vnc daemon

Process exited with code: 0
```

I have a few questions about the processes I ran:

- https://"myPublicIP"/vnc.html. on a separate tab gets a time out and does not load with anything
- In my security group, I have opened up my inbound ports to 22 and 5901, with Source "my IP". Are these correct?
- Does anyone have any success with the above or similar configuration?